# Making properties available in datagridview usercontrol c#

Tags: c#, properties, datagridview, user-controls

Since a few days I've started coding a datagridview with paging. The paging itself works and calculates well. But now I've ran into a problem, I need properties from my custom made user control that aren't available.

In order to be able to use my selfmade usercontrol I need the following properties to be available when exporting it into a .dll file (usercontrol):

- Columns property (datagridview.Columns)
- CurrentRow.Index property (datagridview.CurrentRow.Index)
- Rows.Count property (datagridview.Rows.Count)
- Rows.Cells.Value (datagridview.Rows[counter].Cells[cellcounter].value)
- Column.width property (datagridview.Column.Width)

Could anybody please help me along the way on how to do this / give examples? I have no idea how to get this going.

I've got one property working that I also needed, so I guess this could work as an example :)

```
public void SetColumns( string columnName)
{
    dataGridView.Columns[columnName].Visible = false;
}
```

To make it short: how can I get those properties available in my other projects by coding it in the datagridview? It'll be an usercontrol.

Thank you,
Yenthe

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depends on what exactly you need. 
The first scenario would involve exposing the `DataGridView` itself to the user. In your UserControl:

```
private DataGridView _dataGridView1;

//Lets use a readonly property for this one
//Be careful, readonly property doesn't mean you can't modify the values inside!
public DataGridView UserControlDataGridView 
{
    get
    {
        return _dataGridView1;
    } 
}
```

Then, you'd have control over your DataGridView in your other project.

If you don't want to expose your DataGridView to the user, you'd need to create a property for each item you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Then, you'd have control over your DataGridView in your other project."
Would that mean that I'd have all the properties I need available when I use the dll file in another project then? Such as the .column.width property for example?

Comment: ^ Okay so I found out that is NOT the deal. But how on earth can I tell for example that I want to be able in another project to change the width of a column or something? :s

Comment: Your question is now unclear to me.. can you post more code of your dll and project using it with a precise question?